# How to install Apache Spark History server on macOS

Tags: apache-spark

I have installed Apache Spark using the command 'brew install apache-spark'. But it seems it does not have the history server component.

Answer (score 4):

The script to start Spark HistoryServer is under the Spark's `sbin/` directory. With `brew` installation, that would be `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/<version>/libexec/sbin/`.

To start the historyserver,

```
sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

and to stop

```
sbin/stop-history-server.sh
```